# strange error about python skpy module cannot import name 'Skype' from 'skpy'

Tags: python, skype

when I tried to import it with the python shell it worked great 
but when I tried to run a simple script

```
from skpy import Skype
x=input()
y=input()
try:
   Skype(x,y)
except Exception as e:
    print("not ok:::"+str(e))
```

I got this exception

```
  from skpy import Skype
  ImportError: cannot import name 'Skype' from 'skpy'
```

I am running the script by

```
python script.py
```

but when I worte it through the shell line by line and tied to login there wasn't any problem
I imported and loged in  it like that

```
>>>>from skpy import Skype
>>>> Skype(username,password)
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the same python installation in both cases (you might be using one installation when running the shell, but another when running the script..)

Comment: @Ron I am running the script by python script.py in cmd so in both cases I use the python exe

Comment: @kederrac it also the same version

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps.

1. Go to https://pypi.org/project/SkPy/#files and download the latest version.
2. Extract the files in to a folder and open it in IDE (VS code)
3. Open the terminal and run the command "pip install skpy"
4. Create a file "script.py" in the folder
5. Now paste the code in this file, save it and run it (press f5).

Answer (score 0):

Or just

```
pip install SkPy
```

This will get you the latest version.